# Read a table of number from image (OCR) with different row colour

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, image-recognition, python-tesseract

I want to read a table of number from an attached image (png file).

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import imutils
import pytesseract
import os

image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path, image_name))
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

thresh = 255 - cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (5,5), 0)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')

print(data)
```

Result is:

```
0.74 0.73 0.72
0.72 0.71 0.71
0.71 0.70 0.70
```

As we can see, it misses the row that highlighted in blue.

My question is can we adjust our image such that we can read this missing row correctly?

Comment: Why are you blurring after doing the thresholding? Your image is clean enough that you should not need to blur at all and if so, it is usually done before thresholding to clean up a noisy image.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the data to be read just by resizing the image 2x.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('PBdvo.png')
img_larger = img.resize((img.width*2,img.height*2)) 
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_larger)
print(data)
```

Result:

```
0.74 0.73 0.72
0.73 0.72 0.72
0.72 0.71 0.71
0.71 0.70 0.70
```

---

Edit: based on your new, larger image I came up with the following adjustment:

```
from PIL import ImageFilter

img = Image.open('doc0m.png') 
img_larger = img.resize((round(img.width*2.5),round(img.height*2.5))) 
img_enhanced_more = img_larger.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_enhanced_more)
```

And then I noticed that the data is returned in columns, so if you want it back in rows you can do:

```
for i in zip(*[column.split('\n') for column in data.split('\n\n')]): 
    print(i)
```

Which gives:

```
('1.04', '1.03', '1.03', '1.02', '1.01')
('1.02', '1.01', '1.00', '1.00', '0.99')
('1.00', '0.99', '0.98', '0.97', '0.97')
('0.97', '0.97', '0.96', '0.95', '0.95')
('0.95', '0.95', '0.94', '0.93', '0.92')
('0.93', '0.92', '0.92', '0.91', '0.30')
('0.91', '0.90', '0.90', '0.89', '0.88')
('0.89', '0.88', '0.88', '0.87', '0.86')
('0.87', '0.86', '0.86', '0.85', '0.84')
('0.85', '0.84', '0.84', '0.83', '0.82')
('0.83', '0.82', '0.82', '0.81', '0.80')
('0.81', '0.80', '0.80', '0.79', '0.78')
('0.79', '0.78', '0.78', '0.77', '0.76')
('0.77', '0.76', '0.76', '0.75', '0.74')
('0.76', '0.75', '0.75', '0.74', '0.73')
('0.75', '0.74', '0.74', '0.73', '0.72')
('0.74', '0.74', '0.73', '0.72', '0.72')
('0.73', '0.73', '0.72', '0.71', '0.71')
('0.72', '0.72', '0.71', '0.70', '0.70')
('0.71', '0.71', '0.70', '0.69', '0.69')
('0.71', '0.70', '0.69', '0.69', '0.68')
('0.70', '0.69', '0.68', '0.68', '0.67')
('0.69', '0.68', '0.67', '0.67', '0.66')
('0.68', '0.67', '0.67', '0.66', '0.65')
('0.67', '0.66', '0.66', '0.65', '0.64')
('0.66', '0.65', '0.65', '0.64', '0.63')
('0.65', '0.65', '0.64', '0.63', '0.63')
('0.64', '0.64', '0.63', '0.62', '0.62')
('0.63', '0.63', '0.62', '0.62', '0.61')
('0.63', '0.62', '0.61', '0.61', '0.60')
('0.62', '0.61', '0.60', '0.60', '0.59')
```

Comment: nice and simple!

Comment: @Vorsprung durch Technik Unfortunately this method of resizing the image does not work with a much larger table image (e.g., 60 rows x 5 columns instead of 4 rows x 3 columns as shown in an example). Any suggestions?

Comment: @Vorsprung durch Technik any thoughts on this?

Comment: @MollyBFL: I verified that all of the data is read properly using my new code.

Comment: @Vorsprung durch Technik this is very strange. When I run your code, I did not get the same result. It cannot read properly. It gave out something like "'1,04.', 'Loo', '6.57', 'G81',,...etc". Which version of python and PIL you use? I use python 3.7.3 with PIL version 1.1.7 running on jupyter lab (window 10)

Comment: The version of Python shouldn't matter, I use 3.8. I use Pillow, a fork of PIL: https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

Comment: @Vorsprung durch Technik Thank you very much.

Comment: @Vorsprung durch Technik Actually yes. I just have to update pillow to version 7.0.0. Thank you so much. However, it seems that with different size of image, this code does not seem to work. What is a logic behind the 2.5 resize?

Comment: Trial and error. I just did a few things until it worked.